# How to avoid returning value if the function causes an exception?

Tags: java, exception

```
public int front(){
if(queue.empty()){
  while(!stack.empty()){
    queue.push(stack.pop());
  }
}
try{
  return queue.peek();
}catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Empty");
}
// What to do here?!!!
}
```

I am implementing a `queue` using 2 `stacks`. Here is a function that returns the front element of the `queue` but is the `queue` is `empty` an `exception` must be raised. But there must be a `return` statement outside `try` block and I am confused and don't understand what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What to do here?

If throwing an exception is not an option, there's little you can do when `front()` is called on an empty queue: it is a programming error, so the proper course of action is to throw `IllegalStateException` to indicate that.

```
try{
    return queue.peek();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Empty");
    throw new IllegalStateException("Empty");
}
// return statement is no longer required here
```

All other options are worse from the point of view of API design: you could reserve an `int` value, and return it when the queue is empty, or you could change return type to `Integer` and return `null`, or you could change return type to a pair of `int` and `boolean`, with `boolean` indicating if the read has been successful or not. However, throwing an unchecked exception is more appropriate, because users must check if the queue is empty before asking for its front element.

Comment: How can I return a pair?

Comment: @lord_ozb Make a class with an int and a boolean property, say. `QueueFrontStatus`, and return it instead of `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll stick to throwing unchecked exception :)

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an exception, something on the lines of

```
public int front(){
    //..code
    if(queue.isEmpty()) //or whatever the condition for exception is
        throw new Exception(); //or whatever exception
    else
        return queue.peek(); //return value if exception does not occur
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return an Integer type object and check in the calling code to see if the return value is null. That way if it is null, you can just assume it's empty.

Another thing you could do is have the calling code handle the exception and have the front() method throw the exception like so:

```
public int front() throws Exception {
    if(queue.empty()){
        while(!stack.empty()){
            queue.push(stack.pop());
        }
    }
    return queue.peek();
}
```

This means that whichever method calls front() will have to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'd not do anything where your comment is but you would either return `null` in the `catch` block (making sure that your caller checks the return value for `null` before trying to use the result), or you could throw an exception.